# Getting set of points (cloud) that are given distance in SpatiaLite?

Tags: spatialite

I have a set of points and need to get the groups of points that are within a distance x. 
Ie, determining the point clouds that are up to the distance x from each other.

Additional information:

Example of a table with coordinates (in EPSG:4674)

[image: Table with points EPSG:4674]

The extension of the data is variable. Will be implemented in several counties, separately.

I need anything like this:

[image: clustering buffer]

And I need make this in SQL from SpatiaLite. 
I can make this using buffer and union but I get just one polygon because I don´t have a "group by" attribute, and I need polygons separately for each group.

I´ve been trying this:

```
CREATE TABLE "T_bufEndR" AS 
      SELECT "PK_UID" as "ID_end",
             ST_BUFFER(geom_ce, 0.00025) AS "geom_bu"
        FROM "T_CoordEnd"
       WHERE "situacao" IN (4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "T_unbufEndR" AS
      SELECT ST_UNION(b.geom_bu, a.geom_bu) AS "geom_bu"
        FROM "T_bufEndR" AS "b", "T_bufEndR" AS "a"
       WHERE ST_OVERLAPS(b.geom_bu, a.geom_bu) = 1 AND
             "b"."ROWID" IN (SELECT rowid from SpatialIndex 
                              WHERE f_table_name = "t_bufendr" and
                                    search_frame = "a"."geom_bu")
```

Is that!

Comment: Can you show the table schema and a little bit of your data (e.g. ```SELECT * FROM <table_name> LIMIT 5```). Also please tell us the coordinate reference system you are using, and the extent (coverage area) of your data. Those can all affect the answer.

Comment: Hi @BradHards, I was edit the question for include information. Thanks!

Comment: A question on what you want - do you want to identify sets of points where any of the points are within X distance of each other, or where all of the points are within X distance of each other. So given 4 points (A, B, C and D) evenly spaced on a line, say at distance 2 from each other, what is the expected results if you ask for the cloud of size 3? Also, is it enough to only have the PK_UID in the result?

Comment: @BradHards, I inserted more information about the problem. Sorry for my poor english, ok?

Comment: You haven't answered the question about expected behaviour, but I guess since you've asked the question and been given suggestions on the spatialite mailing list, you've given up here.

Comment: @BradHards, excuse me, I have considered that the above figure would be more efficient to illustrate the problem, sorry... The expected behaviour is identify sets of points where any of the points are within X distance of each other.

Comment: From the SpatiaLite mailing list got the information that may not be possible to do this via pure SQL sentence. The complete tips are on:[GoogleGroups]https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/7IM9L0DJzEc)